# Variance of norm of a random vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We have the formula for any random variable $X \in \mathbb{R}$, $$ \operatorname{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2]= \mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2$$
I am wondering can we do the following for any random vector $Y \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$\operatorname{Var}(||Y||^2)=\mathbb{E}[||Y-\mathbb{E}[Y]||^2]=\mathbb{E}[||Y||^2]-||\mathbb{E}[Y]||^2$$

Comment: What you have written is not valid even for $n=1$. Are you sure you want $\var (\|Y\|^{2}$?

Comment: Yes, I am wondering is there any way to calculate the \var(||Y||^2)

Comment: $$Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2\right)=\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2\right)^2\right]-\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[Y_i^2]\right)^2$$

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\operatorname{Var}$ using `\operatorname{Var}`.